# Entity framework doesn't use JOIN in SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, inner-join, ado.net-entity-data-model

I wrote some code for one to many relationships getting `Invoice` instances from `Defect` instances.

```
mydbEntities ef = new mydbEntities (); //mydbEntities is derived from DbContext
ef.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (s);
Invoice inv = ef.Defects.Where (i => i.Id == 5).SingleOrDefault ().Invoice;
```

That is part of EDM diagram:

[image: EDM diagram]

I'm curious why it did not invoke INNER JOIN, instead of it 2 SQL queries were executed. In the book I'm now reading ("Mastering Entity Framework"), in the same situation an INNER JOIN was invoked.

Output from Debug:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[PositionId] AS [PositionId], 
    [Extent1].[InvoiceId] AS [InvoiceId], 
    [Extent1].[Count] AS [Count], 
    [Extent1].[Reason] AS [Reason]
    FROM [dbo].[Defect] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 5 = [Extent1].[Id]


-- Executing at 6/21/2015 11:21:02 AM +05:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 6/21/2015 11:21:02 AM +05:00

Opened connection at 6/21/2015 11:21:02 AM +05:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Extent1].[InvoiceDate] AS [InvoiceDate]
    FROM [dbo].[Invoice] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 6/21/2015 11:21:02 AM +05:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 6/21/2015 11:21:02 AM +05:00
```

And one more question: How do 2 queries against 1 with INNER JOIN impact on performance in high-loaded application with large database.

Comment: With regards to performance: I an extreme example, both tables contain a million rows but inner joining them will result in ten rows. In seperate queries you are dragging over 2 million rows and joining them in your application. With an inner join the join work is happening on the DB and you are only dragging over 10 rows. For a small number of rows there is probably no difference either way. Basically it's a scaling risk. It works today but it might not work in 3 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EntityFramework (and most other Linq to Sql tools) are only lazy up to a certain point. There are a set of methods that force the query to run. Some examples are:

- `Single`/`SingleOrDefault`
- `First`/`FirstOrDefault`
- `ToList`
- `ToArray`

The trick I use is that each of these methods has an asynchronous version that returns `Task<T>`. So if your autocomplete in your IDE includes `SingleOrDefaultAsync` then it's obvious that `SingleOrDefault` causes the query to be run.

Note that the same behaviour occurs with Linq to Objects; each of the ToList, Single etc. are *eager* methods, whereas the ones that return IEnumerable are *lazy* and get executed on the first eager operation.

To answer your question, the `Include` method fixes this problem by returning the join data. This will improve performance if you use it correctly.

In your example, you are getting the `Invoice` property from your object, so the correct call would be to use `.Include(d => d.Invoice)` or `.Include("Invoice")`. Both of these tell EF to pull back the `Invoice` information in the first query.

Comment: Thanks @Bringer128. Is using Include in case below correct?

Answer (score 2):

You should add .Include(d => d.Invoice) call. Try this:

```
    mydbEntities ef = new mydbEntities (); //mydbEntities is derived from DbContext
    ef.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (s);
    Invoice inv = ef.Defects
        .Include(d => d.Invoice)
        .Where (i => i.Id == 5)
        .SingleOrDefault()
        .Invoice;
```

Comment: And be carefull - you can get NullReferenceException here: .SingleOrDefault().Invoice;